# MVC 3 jQuery UI autocomplete not displaying the results

Tags: json, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-autocomplete

I have searched many times and find examples which match my code structure perfect. Yet I am not getting the results from my ajax to display on the input box.

I get results from the POST that have been evaulated with firebug and everything looks great.

Here is the javascript im using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function () {

    $("input.FamousPerson-List").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/FamousPeople/FPPAutoComplete",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    searchText: request.term,
                    maxResults: 12
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.DisplayName
                        }
                    }))
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Here is a link of the actual code I am using on the web.[AutoCompleteTesting](http://famouspeoplepool.com/Games/Join/1) Type just about any letter in one of the boxes below to invoke it.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried entering text in the boxes and your success function isn't invoked.  Free market research: I want to bet on which celebrities will get fat.  I want to trade cellulite futures on pop stars.

Comment: Well thank you, what am I doing wrong that the success function isn't kicking off? And thank you for the suggestion. The Project is open source and I will be looking for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the request being sent up, you'll notice that a callback parameter is being added. Weird, right? Since you're doing a local AJAX post, not a cross-domain (JSONP) one.

I noticed that your project includes jQuery Validate. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5120621/497356) to a question dealing with a similar problem (performing a JSONP request instead of a normal JSON request even though you asked for one), it's a known issue in jQuery validate.

Judging by the other answer, you can change your version of jQuery or perhaps use a patched version of jQuery validate (found [here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/36)).

Comment: Amazing. Removing the conflicting jQuery Validation version being brought in by the partial view fixes this. Thanks a bunch. The same link above now shows a working solution.